# Strange bug with zoom IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, zooming

I am developing an application with movable charts within a dashboard. Each chart has a set of options in the top right of the element that allows full screening, closing that chart etc. Due to image differences (of which I can't change), I have had to use `zoom` values. This performs exactly as intended in all major browsers, including IE7, but weirdly, not IE9.

http://jsfiddle.net/YkTjp/7/

If you open the fiddle in Chrome and IE9 side by side, you will see the `.icons` element isn't absolutely positioned to `right: 0;`, infact it is twice as far left as it should be. As seen below if you can't recreate it.

[Image here. If someone could edit my post and embed rather than this link I would appreciate it (don't have 10 rep)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82xLZ.jpg)

The bottom picture is what it looks like if i remove `zoom: 0.5;`, and it seems to have the `right` position correct here. So I can only assume its calculating where to place `.icons` BEFORE taking the `zoom` into account.

However, knowing that doesn't put me any closer to a fix. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, since `zoom` is not a standard CSS component, there is no standard for its application.

Basically, the `zoom:0.5` causes the elements to be cut in half, but IE is doing this respective of the space it **would have** occupied, and aligning them top left of that phantom space, rather than aligning just to the parent. It appears much farther from the right, but it actually lines up on the top, and aligns to the left edge of the `zoom:1` components.

Unfortunately, I can't think of a fix for it that isn't Javascript-based, but that is why the problem occurs.